# Querying firebase, without duplication

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to coding and I am just playing around to build an app where everyone can post new events. So I have already created notes like "user" and "events". The problem I face off is that I dont know how to avoid duplication like for example if two users are posting the excat same event.

I don't want to show them twice in my RecyclerView.

So I have to compare the date, the location and the description, due to this many queries, is the Firebase Realtimedatabase the right "tool"? Or should I use another software.

```
------/Events
---------/LbwXYVICCl9xd5m..
--------------datum: 10.04.2019
--------------userid: OncDIQis...
--------------location:New York
--------------description:Coldplay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to define two events as being the same based on some of their properties having the same value. In a scenario like that, I'd use those combined properties as the key of the event.

So if you say that two events are the same if they have the same date, location, and description, then you can create the unique key of that event as `${date}_${location}_${description}`. For example:

```
20190410_New York_Coldplay
```

I've put the date in an easier to search for format, which also filters the `.`s (since those are not allowed in keys. Now you can store the event under that key:

```
Events
  20190410_New York_Coldplay
    datum: 10.04.2019
    userid: OncDIQis...
    location:New York
    description:Coldplay
```

With the above structure, if another user tries to create an equivalent event, it will get the same key.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Real-time database is the right tool for you as it updates the database in real time.
At the time of fetching the data from the firebase, you can check whether it is already present in your local database(where you are collecting data fetched from the firebase) or not.

I hope this will help you out.